# How install mysqldb on virtualenv on mac

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, virtualenv, osx-mavericks

I use Scrapy, 
    i tried to install mysql by `brew install mysql`
but i have this warning:

```
Warning: mysql-5.7.12 already installed
```

if mysql is already installed, why i can't see it in `/etc/init.d/mysql`

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you had previously not fully removed mysql and its components? One method of totally removing mysql from your system would be via the terminal. I found a pretty cut and dry way over at [coolestguidesontheplanet](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/remove-mysql-from-macos-or-osx-via-the-command-line/):

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysq*
sudo rm  /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
```

Navigate to then Edit `/etc/hostconfig` and remove the line with `MYSQLCOM=-YES/NO-`

```
rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql*
```

be sure to investigate as you go along and try to share what the issue was.